# Gulp 4 sass forget to signal async completion

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am trying to build my sass with gulp sass and i get the error:

**The following tasks did not complete: build, gulpSass
Did you forget to signal async completion?**

```
function sass() {
  return gulp.src(paths.sass)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(buildDir));
}

gulp.task('build', gulp.series(
  clean,
  sass,
  html,
  images
));
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Although I cannot see the rest of your code, the problem most likely has to do with a naming collission. I assume you are aliasing the gulp plugin as `sass`. If you did this then there are two variables using the same name.

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
function sass() { ... }
```

The latter overrides the first. So when you call `gulp.task('build', gulp.series(...,sass,...));` It's assuming you're calling the last function. Which has no return statement.

Easily solved by either renaming the alias, to something like `var nodesass = require('gulp-sass');` or renaming the function.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was my issue! I just happened to NOT have my Javascript linter enabled in my code editor otherwise it would have caught this and saved me an hour!

Answer (score 0):

series or gulp.parallel, you have to use async keyword before your function or else you can declare your function with callback as given below.

```
function sass(cb) {
  return gulp.src(paths.sass)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(buildDir));
cb();
}
```

Use this logic in your other functions as well.